# XCode Analyzer Reporting Garbage Ob

Tags: objective-c

```
- (UIImage*)returnRandomBackground{
    int selectedImage = (arc4random() % 4) + 1;
    UIImage *imageToReturn;
    if (selectedImage == 1) {
        imageToReturn = Image1;
    }

    else if (selectedImage == 2) {
        imageToReturn = Image2;
    }

    else if (selectedImage == 3) {
        imageToReturn = Image3;
    }

    else if (selectedImage == 4) {
        imageToReturn = Image4;
    }

    return imageToReturn;
}
```

UnDefined or garbage value returned to caller.

To me this code looks legal, whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will think that it's possible that there's a `selectedImage = 5`, which means there's a possibility of `imageReturn` remaining unassigned. You'll have to change the last `else if` to just an `else` to make sure `imageReturn` is always assigned.

Look at what the code would do if `selectedImage = 5`. It'll break.

Comment: Thank you thats good safety practice i should stick too. An else on an if that could go else where.

Comment: You can also, by the way, tell the right thing to the analyzer by adding and assertion (`assert(selectedImage <= 4)`, or using `NSAssert`) directly after after you assign `selectedImage`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not smart enough to deduce that `(arc4random() % 4) + 1` is always in the range `[1..4]`. Just initialize `imageToReturn` to null and the warning will go away.

**Note:** if you use this, and at some point you change the modulus in the random number generation, you're liable to return `null`s to the caller (with no warning from your friendly compiler) if you don't adapt your `if`/`else` sequence accordingly.
If that is not something you want, use an assertion somewhere (possibly by adding a "catch-all" `else` clause and asserting there).

Also, consider using a `switch` block here instead of the `if`/`else` sequence, that's the most natural construct here in my opinion.

Comment: Because it works around the compiler. Instead of agreeing with the compiler that there can be a path that goes wrong, you tell it to shut up. In my opinion, doing what the compiler tells you always beats ignoring it.

Comment: I disagree in this case. `arc4random` returns an unsigned int. `arc4random()%4` thus yields an unsigned in the range `[0..3]`. The compiler isn't deducing that, and so thinks that there could be a `selectedImage == 5` (or more) case, when this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to actually assign something to created objects.

Comment: @Necro If you did assign something, the compiler wouldn't have told you that your if/else structure is "wrong". Never forget that. ;-)

Comment: @Mat I guess it's a matter of coding style :-)

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: it's not just style, our approaches are very different. Imagine Necro changed that modulo to `%5` but forgot to add a fifth clause. If he changes the last `else if` to an `else`, the code still works but Image4 will be over-represented - hard to track down. If he uses my version, the code will (probably) blow up real fast (20% probability of getting a NPE in the caller). Which one of these outcomes is better for the OP? I don't know. I do prefer code that blows up fast rather than code that works for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively - you could just initialise `imageToReturn`

```
UIImage *imageToReturn = nil;
```

Then, whatever happens, you won't be returning a garbage value.